# Link to Facebook Fanpage Iframe

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, facebook-page

I have a problem with my fanpage. A gallery script is running a my webspace and i put it in the app also in th iframe of the Fanpage. The gallery script has get an Share button to post the photos on facebook. This part of it is running fine but when i clicked the link that was posted in Facebook i had been reffered to my page on my webspace and not to the iframe with the webpage and the photo. Is it possible to edit the link to go to this page in facebook iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem in general. You can try to redirect your website into the Facebook tab application my checking the HTTP_REFERRER and the url. You might have a look at [this example](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609)

There is an URL you can try to call and see if you get redirected to the right application. Additionally, you can add app_data-parameters to the URL to identify the real target into your app.

All that can be done by the following code:

```
// set the target facebook page name and id to perform a forceRedirectToTab()
$tmpFbHelper          
    ->setPageName($iniHandler->getIniSetting('facebook.'.fbHelper::getAppNamespace().'.page.name'))
    ->setPageId($iniHandler->getIniSetting('facebook.'.fbHelper::getAppNamespace().'.page.id'))
    ->setSecret($iniHandler->getIniSetting('facebook.'.fbHelper::getAppNamespace().'.secret'));

// perform a redirect to the facebook tab application if someone opens the url out of facebook
// the facebook-linter is not affected by this :)
$tmpFbHelper->forceRedirectToTab();

// perform a deeplink if for example a special url is called or you identify some app-data 
$tmpFbHelper->performDeeplink();
```

You will have to look at your published links into the stream so that the PHP-code finds out that you will redirect and deeplink!

I hope this ideas might help you :)

Comment: But for this solution i have to pay 10$ for this script. But i dont want to use all the features of this scrpt package. Any other ideas for scripting the reffer?

Comment: 10$ is not that much money ;) ... but you should try the following: The URLs you publish on the stream might be called like domain.com/stream/the-target-link/
Than in your website you create a htaccess redirectUri-rule that redirects all incoming /stream/* request back to the Facebook-App and there you add the rest of the incoming URL ('the-target-link') as &app_data={deeplink:your-target-url} . In your website you test for app_data and the key 'deeplink' ... if this is set you can run a redirect onto this param ;)